# Use one @PropertySource from @PropertySources

Tags: java, spring

I have two DB environments (let's say, "QA1" and "QA2"), every env. has its own '.property' file.

I'm using Spring annotation to describe these envs:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(name = "QA1", value = {"classpath:env/${env:qa1}.properties"}),
        @PropertySource(name = "QA2", value = {"classpath:env/${env:qa2}.properties"})
})
public class DbConfig {

/*some code*/}
```

The question is: how can I choose what actually environment do I need? Like:

```
if (smt=="QA1") { /*use QA1.properties*/}
else {/*use QA2 env*/}
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: I think you are apporaching this problem wrongly. You should `@Profile` and also Load particular properties files based on environment using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`